# interpret cnn structure

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I am trying to interpret the CNN model from the below settings. AS I am new to deep learning and I am not able to fully comprehend the layer structure . Could someone please tell me is these two settings are similar because I read in one research paper they used first setting and wrote that is similar to the second setting

1. A CNN for MNIST with two 5x5 convolution layers (the first with 32 channels, the second with 64, each followed with 2x2 max pooling), a fully connected layer with 512 units and ReLu activation, and a final softmax output layer (1,663,370 total parameters).
2. The CNN for MNIST has 8 layers with the following structure: 3×3×32 Convolutional → 3×3×64 Convolutional → 2×2 MaxPool → Dropout → Flatten → 1 × 128 Full connected → Dropout → 128 × 10 Fully connected → Softmax.

Comment: Can you give a link (or reference) to the paper.

Comment: *Two* 3x3 convolutional layers can have the same "reach" as *one* 5x5 convolutional layer, and uses less weights, so is a design decision that is sometimes made. But, unless you have misquoted it, that doesn't sound like the case here.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.09699.pdf check in section V they mentioned that they are using same setting as previous paper and they defined structure in the fotter on page 7 below section V

Answer (score 0):

1. The CNN for MNIST: 5x5x32 Convolutional -> 2x2 MaxPool -> 5x5x64 Convolutional -> 2x2 MaxPool -> Flatten -> 1x512 Full connected -> ReLu -> 512 x 10 Full connected -> Softmax.
2. The CNN for MNIST has 8 layers with the following structure: 3×3×32 Convolutional → 3×3×64 Convolutional → 2×2 MaxPool → Dropout → Flatten → 1 × 128 Full connected → Dropout → 128 × 10 Fully connected → Softmax.

Converted to both to same formats. They are not the same.